# Is "zu ..., um zu" a German equivalent of "too ... to" or "so ... that ... cannot"?

Tags: expression

> 1 : Ich dachte immer, du wärst viel **zu** beschäftigt, **um zu** deinem Vergnügen zu lesen.

I’m not sure how to interpret the part "um zu". Is it incorrect to omit either of the two words and say:

> Ich dachte immer, du wärst viel **zu** beschäftigt, **um** deinem Vergnügen zu lesen.

Or:

> Ich dachte immer, du wärst viel **zu** beschäftigt, **zu** deinem Vergnügen zu lesen.

---

The following example, on the other hand, takes the form of "zu ... um ...", unlike the "zu ... um zu ..." construction in the first example. I wonder why "zu ... um zu ..." cannot work here?

> 2 : **zu** stolz, **um** nachzugeben
>
> = too proud to give in

Comment: It is not *um zu*, the *zu* is part of *zu deinem Vergnügen*.

Comment: In your second example, "zu" is hidden within "um nachZUgeben", so it also follows the "zu ... um zu" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Only your first sentence is grammatically correct:

> Ich dachte immer, du wärst viel **zu** beschäftigt, **um** *zu*
>   deinem Vergnügen **zu** lesen.
>
> I always thought you were **too** busy **to** read *for* pleasure

As others have pointed out, the "zu" in "*zu* deinem Vergnüngen" is a preposition. I hope the different formatting clarifies that. I'll give you another example:

> Ich dachte immer, du wärst viel **zu** beschäftigt, **um** *mit*
>   deinen Freunden viel Zeit **zu** verbringen.

The conjunction "**um**" cannot be left out!

2: If you use a separable verb in the infinitive clause, "zu" is always included in the verb itself, similarly to the "*ge*" in past participles of separable verbs:

> nachgeben -> nach**zu**geben
>   einkaufen -> ein**zu**kaufen
>   zusehen -> zu**zu**sehen
>   verstehen (not separable) -> **zu** verstehen
>
> Ich bin **zu** stolz, **um** nach**zu**geben.
>   Ich habe **zu** wenig Bargeld, **um** beim Bäcker ein**zu**kaufen.
>   Ich habe **zu** wenig Zeit, **um** dir beim Fußballspiel zu**zu**sehen.
>   Ich bin **zu** müde, **um** komplizierte deutsche Sätze **zu** verstehen.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, there are a couple of subtleties that have confused you.

1. *zu* is both a verbal particle marking extended infinitives (corresponding to *to*+verb) and an adverbial modifier implying excess (corresponding to *too*+adjective in English). (It is also a normal preposition, which can correspond to *to* but also to other English prepositions, as usual.)
2. The role as a verbal particle can be incorporated into the verb if it has a particular stress pattern. Thus, *nachzugeben* is an extended infinitive just as *zu widerstehen* is.

Now for your question. Both particles are obligatory in your example sentence, but for different reasons. Omitting the *zu* in an extended infinitive is simply wrong. "...um zu deinem Vergnügen lesen" sounds strange to German ears. Omitting the *um* in *um...zu* is borderline acceptable:

> Ich war zu beschäftigt, den Brief abzuschicken.

*could* be understood as "I was too busy to send the letter". However, it's dispreferred because it is ambiguous: it might just as well be taken to mean "I was too busy sending the letter"! You should normally use both markers in every such construction.

Comment: Hi. So does the original sentence mean "**too** busy **to** read **for** your pleasure" or "so busy that you cannot read for your pleasure"? Actually, what had me puzzled was the existence of the "zu(for)" placed immediately before "deinem Vergnügen". Now I see where I was wrong. :)  Merci.

Comment: Incidentally, is it considered redundant to add "sein" to the original sentence? "Ich dachte immer, du wärst viel zu beschäftigt **sein**, um zu deinem Vergnügen zu lesen."

Comment: @Alone-zee That would be quite wrong. Both *wärst* and *sein* are forms of the verb "sein", and "sein" doesn't take a verbal complement. The only correct use of "sein" appearing twice in a verb phrase is in forming the perfect tense: "Ich *bin* im Urlaub *gewesen*."

Comment: Oh, thanks. If you omit the prepositional phrase "zu deinem Vergnügen", can you say "**zu** beschäftigt, **um zu** lesen"?